# How to make an unattended Ubuntu install

Tags: linux

I need to know how to make an unattended Ubuntu install. I've tried and so far it just crashes when trying to fill in the timezone.

Comment: If it crashes, maybe you tried wrong. (In other words: there's *far* from enough information you've given. What methods exactly have you tried so far?)

Comment: I think your best bet would be to create an image of what is to be installed, and copy that.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here before, in a similar fashion. It should be useful in your case as well.

https://askubuntu.com/a/122506/53851